# Why is simulator very slow when using CIFilter

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, simulator

I am using CIFilter to create image filter and show it on a image view. What happen is that it works fine on a iphone device but works very slow on simulator. Below is the code. I wander why simulator is so slow compare to the device. Is there a way to increase simulator memory or cpu in order to make it work as similar as a device?

```
func outputImage(filter: CIFilter, originalImage: UIImage) -> UIImage{
    print(filter)
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: originalImage)
    filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let outputImage =  filter.outputImage
    let cgImage = context!.createCGImage(outputImage!, fromRect: (outputImage?.extent)!)
    return UIImage(CGImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, just guess because of the GPU?

Answer (score 0):

Check  `Debug -> Toggle Slow Animations` is Unchecked you might accidentally checked, this is also a cause of performance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked that I didn't check Slow Animations

Answer (score 0):

> I wander why simulator is so slow compare to the device

It's because the simulator doesn't use the GPU. The Xcode 11 / Catalina combination is the first to use the GPU in the simulator.